# The structure of $G/\{e_G\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Suppose $G$ is a group. Lets consider its trivial subgroup, i.e. $\{e_G\}$. Since trivial subgroup is normal in $G$ then  $G/\{e_G\}$ is group. From the definition of quotient group we know that $$G/\{e_G\}:=\{g\{e_G\}:g\in G\}$$
since $g\{e_G\}=\{ge_G\}=\{g\}$ then $G/\{e_G\}=\{\{{g}\}:g\in G\}$. Could we say that $G/\{e_G\}=G$ i.e. they are the same. I know that they are isomorphic but is it correct to say that they are identical.

If not please explain that.

Comment: No, they are not identical as sets.

Comment: Although they're not identical as sets, they are "canonically isomorphic" in the sense that the projection $G \to G/\{e\}$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot say $G/\{e_G\}=G$.

If $g$ is an element of $G$, then $G/\{e_G\}$ contains the element $\{g\}$, which is not the same. They are, however, clearly isomorphic.

Comment: What is the significant difference between $g$ and $\{g\}$?

Comment: @RFZ Define "significant"...

Comment: @RFZ $g$ and $\{g\}$ are different objects in the sense that they are not the same object. The statement $g=\{g\}$ is a false statement.

Comment: Sorry let's remove that word. What is the difference between $g$ and $\{g\}$? The first one is just element but the second one is the set. Right?

Comment: @RFZ Correct. An object is not the same thing as a set containing the object, just like an orange is not the same thing as a bag with an orange inside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining! I accept it as the best answer. +1

Comment: Confusion is easy.  It is common to say things such as "there is only one group of order 3" but this example shows us how to find another.  The explanation is that there is usually an unspoken "up to isomorphism".  Here we are being more precise.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct, since $e_G\neq\{e_G\}$. Of course, the fact that they are isomorphic is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for answer!